std::make_unique array leads to corrupted top size error
Depending on how to create my unique_ptr, it either works or it leads to malloc(): corrupted top size error on execution.
This leads to the mentioned error
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t*>, size_t> getBinaryData( const std::filesystem::path &sourcePath )
{
    std::ifstream filestream ( sourcePath, std::ios::binary );

    const size_t filesize = std::filesystem::file_size(sourcePath);

    std::cout << "Input file size: " << filesize << " bytes\n";
    
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t*> buffer = std::make_unique<uint8_t*>( new uint8_t[ filesize ] );
    if ( !filestream.read( ( char* )( buffer.get() ), filesize ) )
    {
        std::cout << << "Reading from file " << sourcePath << " failed." << "\n";
    }
    
    filestream.close();

    return { std::move( buffer ), filesize };
}

int main()
{
    auto [memoryPtr, length] = getBinary( "myfile.bin" );
}

and this works:
std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t, std::default_delete<uint8_t[]>>, size_t> getBinaryData( const std::filesystem::path &sourcePath )
{
    std::ifstream filestream ( sourcePath, std::ios::binary );

    const size_t filesize = std::filesystem::file_size(sourcePath);

    std::cout << "Input file size: " << filesize << " bytes\n";

    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t, std::default_delete<uint8_t[]>> buffer( new UInt8_t[ filesize ] );
    if ( !filestream.read( ( char* )( buffer.get() ), filesize ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Reading from file " << sourcePath << " failed." << "\n";
    }
    
    filestream.close();

    return { std::move( buffer ), filesize };
}

but I don't like the 2nd solution because I have to write std::default_delete<uint8_t[]> everywhere.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong in the 1st approach?
Also it would be interesting to know why this doesn't work:
std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<uint8_t*>, size_t> getBinaryData( const std::filesystem::path &sourcePath )
{
    std::ifstream filestream ( sourcePath, std::ios::binary );

    const size_t filesize = std::filesystem::file_size(sourcePath);

    std::cout << "Input file size: " << filesize << " bytes\n";

    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t*> buffer( new uint8_t[ filesize ] );
    if ( !filestream.read( ( char* )( buffer.get() ), filesize ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Reading from file " << sourcePath << " failed." << "\n";
    }
    
    filestream.close();

    return { std::move( buffer ), filesize };
}


There's a difference between std::unique_ptr<Type*> and std::unique_ptr<Type[]>, are you aware of it?

@Abstraction No I am not, I thought they are the same?

std::unique_ptr<uint8_t*> manages uint8_t**. It has to be std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> for it to handle array correctly.

How about std::vector<uint8_t>?

@Jarod42 I have to carry std::default_delete<uint8_t[]> because otherwise it leeds to mismatched free / delete due to G++ only calling delete on the array

Not sure what you mean, but std::vector<uint8_t> getBinaryData(const std::filesystem::path&) would be fine too.

Also, consider using std::make_unique instead of new, it would've caught this error.


C++ imposes a strict distinction between new/delete and new[]/delete[]. You may not allocate memory with one operator and then free it with another.
std::unique_ptr<Type> invokes delete on destruction and std::make_unique<Type>() invokes new. std::unique_ptr<Type[]> invokes delete[] on destruction and std::make_unique<Type[]> accepts the size of array as its argument and invokes new[].
std::unique_ptr<Type*> invokes delete on destruction and frees the pointer of type Type*, not the memory it's pointing to.

With all that in mind, let's look at the code:
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t*> buffer = std::make_unique<uint8_t*>( new uint8_t[ filesize ] );    

Here you allocate an array of filesize elements of uint8_t, then allocate 1 object of type uint8_t* and copy the address of the array into that variable. The address of that address is stored in buffer.
if ( !filestream.read( ( char* )( buffer.get() ), filesize ) )

buffer.get() returns the value of type uint8_t**, a pointer pointing to a pointer-sized memory block. You C-style cast it to char* and try to write filesize bytes into it. If filesize is greater than sizeof(uint8_t*), you're writing outside allocated memory. Anything can happen at this point, you're lucky if your program simply crashes. In all likelihood, at this point you damage internal heap structures.
return { std::move( buffer ), filesize };

In case filesize <= sizeof(uint8_t*) you (properly) return the buffer variable. Eventually it will be destroyed and the memory owned by buffer (the size of a pointer) will be properly freed. If the heap was corrupted above, this would be the point where library functions may "notice" it. Either way, the filesize-sized block you've also allocated will never be freed, the memory has "leaked".
In another attempt, you write
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t*> buffer( new uint8_t[ filesize ] );

Here you again allocate filesize elements of uint8_t and try to write the address of that block into buffer. However, the compiler should object that the constructor of std::unique_ptr<uint8_t*> accepts uint8_t**, not uint8_t* the result of new[] may be implicitly cast to.
If you somehow bypass this type error, no memory leak occurs. buffer.get() will return uint8_t** but on any non-exotic architecture C-style casting it to char* will result in the address of the allocated block. Unfortunately, on destruction buffer will invoke delete (since it can't tell whether you stored an array or just a single value) and you'll get a new[]/delete mismatch which, once again, will at best crash your program immediately and may introduce arcane-looking bugs into your application.
What you could do:
    //no manual "new"!
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> buffer = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(filesize);
    //the rest is the same sans changing uint8_t* to uint8_t[]

However, most of the time you're better off using std::vector<uint8_t> instead. Pointer-to-array does not store the size (which is why you had to return a tuple) and makes it easy to address values outside allocated memory.

When using std::make_...() functions, its simpler to use auto to ensure you have the correct variable type, eg: auto buffer = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(filesize);
